# error parsing k8s-geneva-redis-no-secty.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 92: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: yaml, microk8s

Tried to install edgexfoundry installation on microk8s, using below command

microk8s.kubectl apply -f k8s-geneva-redis-no-secty.yml

Getting error: error parsing k8s-geneva-redis-no-secty.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 92: mapping values are not allowed in this context

But the same file used on kubernetis using below command
kubectl apply -f k8s-geneva-redis-no-secty.yml, it worked and all the pods were running.

Ref URL:- https://github.com/edgexfoundry/edgex-examples/tree/master/deployment/kubernetes

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is not much anyone can help with if you don't provide the source file causing the error.

Answer (score -1):

Its working after formatting the .yml file.

Error code:

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
  name: edgex-core-consul
  spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
  app: edgex-core-consul
  ports:
  - name: tcp-8500
  port: 8500
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 8500
  nodePort: 30850
  - name: tcp-8400
  port: 8400
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 8400
  nodePort: 30840

Updated code:

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
  name: edgex-core-consul
  spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
  app: edgex-core-consul
  ports:
  - name: tcp-8500
  port: 8500
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 8500
  nodePort: 30850
  - name: tcp-8400
  port: 8400
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 8400
  nodePort: 30840

Comment: None of your above examples are displayed correctly in your answer since you did not use code blocks. Moreover, looking at your source, none of them is correctly formatted anyway to be a correct yaml file. Formatting yaml correctly is not an option just to beautify it: indentation is part of the yaml syntax. For a quick start, you can [learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)